# Не могу увеличить динамический блок menu до конца страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, height

1)Хочу сделать блок menu до конца страницы.
2) Не понимаю откуда появляется height = 767px.

Лишний мусор - для полноты картины.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Miron188/9h6gayj1/2/
```

HTML

```
<div id = "menu">

<div id = "serch"></div>

<div class = "tape">Теги HTML</div>
<div class ="tape1"></div>

<div id = "menuContainer1">
 </div>

 <div class = "tape">Справочник CSS</div>
<div class ="tape1"></div>

 <div id = "menuContainer2">

 </div>
```

CSS

```
    #menu{
 position:relative;
 height:100%;
 float: left;
 width:210px; 
 background:  #4b4a45 repeat;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    background: #4b4a45 repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="menu">

            <div id="serch"></div>

            <div class="tape">Теги HTML</div>
            <div class="tape1"></div>

            <div id="menuContainer1">
            </div>

            <div class="tape">Справочник CSS</div>
            <div class="tape1"></div>

            <div id="menuContainer2">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```